# How to add a reference line to a Normal Q-Q vs. Random Effects plot generated with plot.rlmerMod?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lme4, mixed-models, robust

I ran a robust mixed effects model with the `rlmer` command implemented in the `robustlmm` package. The package includes a plotting function `plot.lmerMod` for residual analysis, the resulting plots are `ggplot` objects. As you can see in the example below I managed to add a reference line to the Q-Q vs. residuals plot (see below). However, I'm unsure how to do this for the random effects (RE) Q-Q plot. Through the `getMe`function several "components" are accessible. I extracted the *conditional mode of the “spherical” random effects variable* which is represented by ``u```. The lines in the resulting plot appear to be fine but I'm really not sure if that is the right thing to do?

```
library(lme4)
library(robustlmm)
library(ggplot2)

fit <- rlmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)

# Q-Q versus residuals
QQ1 <- plot.rlmerMod(fit, which=2)
QQ1[[1]]+
  stat_qq_line(aes(sample=resid(fit)))

# Q-Q versus RE
RE <- getME(fit,name = c("u"))
QQ2 <- plot.rlmerMod(fit, which=3)
QQ2[[1]]+
  stat_qq_line(aes(sample=RE2))
```

[image: Normal Q-Q vs. Residuals]
[image: Normal Q-Q vs. Random Effects]